# sendmsg returns ECONNREFUSED on SCTP socket

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a third-party code using SCTP, and I observed that sometimes `sendmsg` returns -1 and sets `errno` to ECONNREFUSED, although this is not described in man pages on my system (Ubuntu). I checked sendmsg implementation in net/sctp/socket.c of the kernel and it *seems* it does not return ECONNREFUSED, although I may be missing something.

So, my question really is it possible that sending buffer on SCTP would result in such an error? Probably it has to do with the underlying SCTP transport infrastructure which is very different from TCP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you misread the error code by mistake? What is the actual value of `errno`? What does e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) tell you? What are you actually *doing* (i.e. can you perhaps try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us)?

Comment: The error code returned is 111. The code uses `perror` which says "Connection refused".